# Error 1004 method range of object failed?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm almost done with a project that updates existing sheets of data. But there is just one error that keeps me from selecting the range of data I would like to import from a new file

```
ChDir "C:\Users\jiarui.hou.THRUBIT\Desktop"
Dim aFile As String
Dim SheetName As String
aFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Raw Data File to Import")
If aFile = "False" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=aFile

'Returns LAST USED cell
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows,   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
LastCell = Cells(LastRow, LastColumn).Address
Range(A1 & ":" & LastCell).Select 'Error 1004:method'Range' of object '_Global' failed
Selection.Copy
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try:

```
Range("A1:" & LastCell).Select
```

If you are wanting to select from A1 to the LastCell.  Without the quotes, A1 is just a variant according to my Locals window, in that snippet of code.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Just one other related question, so that I will know what syntax to use next time I see these kinds of problems. I did a range.select earlier with rows instead of cells. and I used: Range(1 & ":" & LastRow).Select instead how come this kinds of format doesnt work for cells. Can you give me other related argument syntax for the range.select functions?? Thanks

Comment: Within VBA, highlight the `Range` keyword and press F1... you'll see that there are several `Range` methods. Maybe for this reason you didn't have problems.